# Calling a CUDA-enabled library in a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda

I have some code that i have written and put into it's own library that uses CUDA to do some processing on the GPU.

I am building a GUI front-end using Qt, and as part of loading the GUI, I call

```
CUresult res;
CUdevice dev;
CUcontext ctx;

    cuInit(0);
    cuDeviceGet(dev,0);
    cuCtxCreate(ctx, 0, dev);
```

to go ahead and initialize the GPU, so that the application is responsive as possible when calling the CUDA-enabled library.

The problem is, I have now started trying to call my CUDA-enabled library from a different thread.

Do I have to make some kind of effort to do this? That other thread is the ONLY one calling any cuda functions (except for the main thread calling cuInit()), but my code is crashing on a cudaFree() call in my cuda library.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Contexts are tied to the thread that created them. So your two choices are either to have the GPU "worker thread" establish the context, or use the driver API context migration calls ([cuCtxPopCurrent](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDA__CTX_g2fac188026a062d92e91a8687d0a7902.html) and [cuCtxPushCurrent](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDA__CTX_gb02d4c850eb16f861fe5a29682cc90ba.html#gb02d4c850eb16f861fe5a29682cc90ba)) to move the context from thread to thread. Be aware that context migration isn't free, so if you are going to do it a lot, you will notice an increase in GPU latency.

Comment: I tried to put in a call to cuCtxPopCurrent() in my worker thread, but it seems to return a null result in the worker thread

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally use the driver API so I can't offer direct advice other than it's easy to get confused between `cuCtxPopCurrent()` and `cuCtxPushCurrent()`.

But definitely check out the [CUDA Toolkit 4.0 Readiness Tech Brief](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_4.0_Readiness_Tech_Brief.pdf).  CUDA 4.0 made some big changes to how multi-threaded and multi-gpu stuff works, it's worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have employed in the past (Cuda 2.2) is also the GPU "worker thread" paradigm, where a single, dedicated thread manages the CUDA context.

A very general approach (using boost::bind to forward function calls) can be seen at http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=66598

Example code from the link:

```
GPUWorker gpu0(0);
GPUWorker gpu1(1);

// allocate data
int *d_data0;
gpu0.call(bind(cudaMalloc, (void**)((void*)&d_data0), sizeof(int)*N));
int *d_data1;
gpu1.call(bind(cudaMalloc, (void**)((void*)&d_data1), sizeof(int)*N));

// call kernel
gpu0.callAsync(bind(kernel_caller, d_data0, N));
gpu1.callAsync(bind(kernel_caller, d_data1, N));
```

The GPUWorker object accepts function objects through the call method, which are pushed onto a queue. The GPUWorker::run() will then pop off the function objects and call them in the proper CUDA context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the Cuda library from a different thread rather than the thread that created the Context, you will have to explicitly pop the Context (cuCtxPopCurrent(handle)) from the context creation thread and push the returned context handle to the worker thread (cuCtxPushCurrent(*handle)).

In your case, you can initialize the Cuda device in the main thread, but create the context in the worker thread and the context will be attached to worker thread upon creation.