# Use Multithreads in MFC C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I amnew to using multithreads on CPU, MFC C++. I am trying to initialize two of the CWinThreads and run them simultaneously as worker threads, here it is in my header file

```
    CWinThread      *m_thread;  
    CWinThread      *m_thread1;
```

In my cpp file i am trying to call them like this

```
    CdecoderD3D9App *decoder_object_1 = new CdecoderD3D9App(460, 1);
    m_thread = AfxBeginThread(MainTread, decoder_object_1);

    CdecoderD3D9App *decoder_object_2 = new CdecoderD3D9App(460, 2);
    m_thread1 = AfxBeginThread(MainTread1, decoder_object_2);
```

`CdecoderD3D9App` is my app class that i am passing to the threads and running its functions my threads functions are like this

```
UINT Ctesting_projectDlg::MainTread(LPVOID pParam)

{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock(); 
    CdecoderD3D9App *decoder_object_1 = (CdecoderD3D9App *)pParam;
    char *video_source = "my_movie.mp4";



    decoder_object_1->InitInstance();

    decoder_object_1->run_program(video_source);


    t2 = clock(); 
    float diff = (((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000000.0F ) * 10;


    return 0;
}


UINT Ctesting_projectDlg::MainTread1(LPVOID pParam)

{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock(); 
    CdecoderD3D9App *decoder_object_3 = (CdecoderD3D9App *)pParam;

    char *video_source = "my_movie.m2v";



    decoder_object_3->InitInstance();




    decoder_object_3->run_program(video_source);
    t2 = clock(); 
    float diff = (((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000000.0F ) * 10;

    return 0;
}
```

When I am calling the thread functions only the second thread is running, the first thread start to run but as soon as the second thread is call upon the first thread stops. Is there anyway i can run them both simultaneously?
I have to run basically four threads like these simultaneously in the program. Thank you.

Comment: Are you linking with the multithreaded versions on the C++ runtime? If not then you may be getting some internal runtime corruption that is affecting the other thread.

Comment: Maybe `CdecoderD3D9App::run_program` cannot run in more than one thread, because of some internal limitations.

Comment: I am doing the same and have the library included. Sorry i am new but i think so i am linking them to the multithreaded version of C++ runtime

Comment: @Dialecticus.. For CdecoderD3D9App I am creating two different objects, Should not it be working for both ?
Also this class is basically modified class for H.264 decoder example of CUDA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
CWinThread *pThread;
pThread = AfxBeginThread (TestStartThread
                             ,param,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
```

here, TestStartThread is the function and param is a pointer to the TestStartThread s' input arguments.

define TestStartThread(...) like this,

```
static UINT TestStartThread (LPVOID param);
```

call what ever your function inside TestStartThread static function as desired.

If you are new refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14746/Multithreading-Tutorial

Comment: I have tried that too. The first thread starts but as soon as the second thread is call it just pass the thread on or something and stops executing.

Comment: Can you find out at which point first thread going to stop . . .

Comment: yes as soon as the second thread is called the first completely stops and the second thread is executed. Its like a complete shutdown like only one thread is there rather than two.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709291/calling-a-cuda-enabled-library-in-a-new-thread

Comment: and this https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/390598/cuda-programming-and-performance/gpuworker-master-slave-multi-gpu-approach/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37099/discussion-between-hadi-and-anjana)

Comment: @Hadi You got this, any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your worker threads are actually GUI threads, based on the InitInstance and run_program(video_source).  While you can have technically have multiple gui threads under MFC, you might be better off with separate processes and some inter-process communications.

Comment: Basically the initInstance and run_program is running and initializing a CUDA instance and running multithreading there on CUDA. Can it be a problem considering i am trying to process CUDA program from a single program using different threads.. ?